# how to get type of select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

How I can get type of a select element using jquery?I mean I get that a specific element is DropDownList or ListBox?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are

```
if ($("#select_id").attr("size") > 0) {
    // listbox
}
else {
    // dropdown
}
```

Comment: you probably should changr comment order

Comment: ahh sorry about that, changed it

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $('#id').prop('multiple') ) {
  alert('multiple');
} else {
  alert('single');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NNfYn/

Edit: changed attr to prop, thanks @lolwut

Comment: that not works.Consider I have a DropDownList and ListBox.I want to get type of the element usnig jQuery

Comment: You would usually would want to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Sorry but when Asp.net render a list box or dropdownliist,It does not render 'multiple' propperties

Comment: @Nima, then what's the generated html in both cases?

Comment: select element.for ListBox it generate a `size` attribute.Can I use this attribute to determine type of select?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('selectlist').getAttribute('size')
```